# Javascript use variable as object name

Tags: javascript

I want to use the value of a variable to access an object.

Let's say I have an object named myobject.

I want to fill a variable with this name and use the variable to access the object.

Example:

```
var objname = 'myobject';
{objname}.value = 'value';
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Global:**

```
myObject = { value: 0 };
anObjectName = "myObject";
this[anObjectName].value++;

console.log(this[anObjectName]);
```

**Global: v2**

```
var anObjectName = "myObject";
this[anObjectName] = "myvalue"

console.log(myObject)
```

**Local: v1**

```
(function() {
    var scope = this;

    if (scope != arguments.callee) {
        arguments.callee.call(arguments.callee);
        return false;
    }

    scope.myObject = { value: 0 };
    scope.anObjectName = "myObject";
    scope[scope.anObjectName].value++;

    console.log(scope.myObject.value);
})();
```

**Local: v2**

```
(function() {  
    var scope = this;

    scope.myObject = { value: 0 };
    scope.anObjectName = "myObject";
    scope[scope.anObjectName].value++;

    console.log(scope.myObject.value);    
}).call({});
```

Comment: @Shaz -- both of those reference the same scope actually ;-) (Assuming they are executed in a browser.)  `alert(this === window)`.

Comment: @Sean: They are. And they do?

Comment: @PeeHaa - The **Local** example sets a variable on the `window` object called `objname` which is then referenced via `this` ... you could substitute `window` for `this` in the second example and everything would still work. :-)

Comment: @SeanVieira: Take a look at the updated example. Hopefully this works correctly now.

Comment: @Shaz -- `arguments.callee` is deprecated, but it's a *very* clever implementation nonetheless -- **and** it doesn't litter the global scope. +1

Comment: It may not be polluting the global scope, but it's creating an object that is shared by every invocation of the function. Your function is holding `objname` as a property of the function itself. It can fail for recursive functions. Not sure how this can be used in the real world.

Comment: @Sean @Juan I've updated version 2 which does not use `arguments.callee`.

Comment: @Shaz can we use the `Function` keyword here?If yes then please explain how.I was thinking of something like in here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078655/extract-call-javascript-function-defined-in-the-onclick-html-attribute-of-an-e

Answer (score 45):

Use square bracket around variable name.

```
var objname = 'myobject';
{[objname]}.value = 'value';
```

Comment: This throws an exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'. It does not work; why so many upvotes?

Comment: Thanks for simple and perfect answer!

Comment: This is what I was searching for!

Answer (score 10):

Is it a global variable? If so, these are actually part of the `window` object, so you can do `window[objname].value`.

If it's local to a function, I don't think there's a good way to do what you want.

Answer (score 9):

The object exists in some scope, so you can almost always access the variable via this syntax:

```
var objname = "myobject";
containing_scope_reference[objname].some_property = 'some value';
```

The only place where this gets tricky is when you are in a closed scope and you want access to a top-level local variable.   When you have something like this:

```
(function(){
    var some_variable = {value: 25};
    var x = "some_variable";
    console.log(this[x], window[x]); // Doesn't work
})();
```

You *can* get around that by using `eval` instead to access the current scope chain ... but I don't recommend it unless you've done a lot of testing and you **know** that that's the best way to go about things.

```
(function(){
    var some_variable = {value: 25};
    var x = "some_variable";
    eval(x).value = 42;
    console.log(some_variable); // Works
})();
```

Your *best* bet is to have a reference to a name in an always-going-to-be-there object (like `this` in the global scope or a private top-level variable in a local scope) and put *everything* else in there.

Thus:

```
var my_outer_variable = {};
var outer_pointer = 'my_outer_variable';
// Reach my_outer_variable with this[outer_pointer]
// or window[outer_pointer]

(function(){
    var my_inner_scope = {'my_inner_variable': {} };
    var inner_pointer = 'my_inner_variable';
    // Reach my_inner_variable by using
    // my_inner_scope[inner_pointer]
})();
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use `eval`:

```
eval(variablename + ".value = 'value'");
```

Comment: Isn't `eval` considered `evil`? If not I might use it. Because it is a global right now but I wanted to move it into a function to clean up stuff.

Comment: Lol. If the variable name comes from user input, make sure you validate it, so that it doesn't contain any JS code that `eval` can execute.

Comment: @Midas: it doesn't come directly from user input. But from an HTML element's data content. Which the user of course can manipulate. However I don't see what's so bad if the user can execute his own JS code. It only get executed on the client or am I missing something?

Comment: This is one of the few legitimate uses of `eval`, in my opinion.  We have to make sure the variable is clean, though.

Comment: Yes it's not really a problem. But take a look at the answer from Shaz. I think that's a more clean solution.

Comment: @PeeHaa: If you're considering moving it, why not move it into a property of a known object, so you can do something like `myVar[objname].value`?

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this in general, except at the window scope, where you can write `window[objname].value = 'value';`

Answer (score 4):

I think Shaz's answer for local variables is hard to understand, though it works for non-recursive functions. Here's another way that I think it's clearer (but it's still his idea, exact same behavior). It's also not accessing the local variables dynamically, just the property of the local variable.

Essentially, it's using a global variable (attached to the function object)

```
// Here's  a version of it that is more straight forward.
function doIt() {
    doIt.objname = {};
    var someObject = "objname";
    doIt[someObject].value = "value";    
    console.log(doIt.objname);
})();
```

Which is essentially the same thing as creating a global to store the variable, so you can access it as a property. Creating a global to do this is such a hack.

Here's a cleaner hack that doesn't create global variables, it uses a local variable instead.

```
function doIt() {
  var scope = {
     MyProp: "Hello"
  };
  var name = "MyProp";
  console.log(scope[name]);
}
```

See [Javascript: interpret string as object reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953303/javascript-interpret-string-as-object-reference/10953396#10953396)

Answer (score 4):

Square brackets can be used to make key dynamic like this

```js
var myObjKey = "key";

var obj = {[myObjKey] : "value" };
console.log(obj); // => {key: 'value'}

var anotherObj = {["justString"] : "value" };
console.log(anotherObj ); // => {justString: 'value'}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let players = [];
players[something] = {};
players[something].somethingElse = 'test';
console.log(players);
```

-> [ something: { somethingElse: 'test' } ];

Answer (score 1):

If object is in some namespace ie. `Company.Module.Components.Foo` you can use this function:

CoffeeScript:

```
objByName: (name, context = window) ->
    ns = name.split "."
    func = context
    for n, i in ns
        func = func[n]
    return func
```

Resulted Js:

```
objByName: function(name, context) {
  var func, i, n, ns, _i, _len;
  if (context == null) {
    context = window;
  }
  ns = name.split(".");
  func = context;
  for (i = _i = 0, _len = ns.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
    n = ns[i];
    func = func[n];
  }
  return func;
}
```

Then you can create a new object or do whatever. Note the parenthises through.

```
var o = new (objByName('Company.Module.Components.Foo'))
objByName('some.deeply.nested.object').value
```

This idea is borrowed from similar question: [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

One of the challenges I had with the answers is that it assumed that the object was a single level. For example,

```
const testObj = { testKey: 'testValue' }
const refString = 'testKey';
const refObj = testObj[refString];
```

works fine, but

```
const testObj = { testKey:
                  { level2Key: 'level2Value' }
                }
const refString = 'testKey.level2Key';
const refObj = testObj[refString];
```

does not work.

What I ended up doing was building a function to access multi-level objects:

```
objVar(str) {
    let obj = this;
    const parts = str.split('.');
    for (let p of parts) {
        obj = obj[p];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

In the second scenario, then, I can pass the string to this function to get back the object I'm looking for:

```
const testObj = { testKey:
                  { level2Key: 'level2Value' }
                }
const refString = 'testObj.testKey.level2Key';
const refObj = objVar[refString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an objects property this way:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.whateverVarName = 'yourVal';
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the list of the possible varible names then try creating a new Object(iconObj) whose properties name are same as object names, 
Here in below example, iconLib variable will hold two string values , either 'ZondIcons' or 'MaterialIcons'.  propertyName is the property of ZondIcons or MaterialsIcon object.

```
   const iconObj = {
    ZondIcons,
    MaterialIcons,
  }
  const objValue = iconObj[iconLib][propertyName]
```

Answer (score -1):

When using the window[objname], please make sure the objname is global variables.
Otherwise, will work sometime, and fail sometimes.
window[objname].value.