# Safely using eval to use variable as an object name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, eval

As shown in this example

[javascript-use-variable-as-object-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084858/javascript-use-variable-as-object-name)

I am using eval to use a DOM attribute to select an element from an array. Though there is no direct way for the user to change the input, I want to be as secure as possible and make sure that the variable is indeed an integer before I evaluated it.

Which of the following would be the best, most secure, way?

```
$(".listitem").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("record-id");
    if(!isNaN(new Number(id))){
        Storage.search.nearby.currec = rowsHolder[eval(id)];
    }else{
        // send email to admin, shut down
    }
});
```

or

```
$(".listitem").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("record-id");
    if(parseInt(id)){
        Storage.search.nearby.currec = rowsHolder[eval(id)];
    }else{
        // send email to admin, shut down
    }
});
```

More, but not required info:

Basically I am pulling down a large JSON string from online, containing an array of records. Upon building a table from the info using a for statement ( *for(i in array)* ), I push each row into an array called *rowsHolder* and give the tr an attribute of *record-id="i"*. Then when the user clicks the row, I call the method you see above. I am using PhoneGap with JQuery Mobile.

As always, thanks for the input

-D

Comment: Why would you need to eval that? if for some strange reason you need a string for the object key, use toString().

Comment: I'm not clear on what kind of values would be contained in `id`. Is it just numbers? Or variable names? Or long members chains like `obj.foo.bar.baz`?

Comment: What's wrong with just `rowsHolder[id]`?

Comment: @deceze - rowsHolder[id] gives me undefined - i assume that it takes id not to be the var, but to be literally "id", but eval(id) gives me the object I need

Comment: @apsillers - id would contain the array key, 0, 1, 2, ... n

Comment: @user399696: No, it uses the value of the variable `id` for the property name. Show us the `rowsHolder` object and the value of `id` (`console.log(JSON.stringify(rowsHolder, null, 4), id);`)

Comment: @adeneo - it isn't a string I'm after, but an array key

Comment: @Bergi - That gives me the array of all of the objects for all of the rows: [
    {
        "id": "00088"
    },
    {
        "id": "00078"
    },
    {
        "id": "00068"
    },
    {
        "id": "00017"
    },
    {
        "id": "00019"
    }
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to use `eval` here.

- If your `id` is kind of a number, use `parseFloat(id)` to get it. Unnecessary as it would be converted back to a string when used as a property name, though.
- If your `id` is an integer, use `parseInt(id, 10)` to get it. Unnecessary as it would be converted back to a string when used as a property name, though.
- If your `id` is a string, just let it be a string. The property name you use it for would be one anyway.

Comment: Though  I don't have a way to debug to see the error, the line Storage.search.currec.record = rowsHolder[parseInt(id)]; breaks the script such that nothing happens on the click event. Storage.search.currec.record = rowsHolder[eval(id)]; is fine though

Comment: The reason I have to use eval, it seems to me, is that - like Bergi says above - the script thinks I'm trying to find and object property called "id", when I'm actually trying to find an array key (or object property) called "0" or "3" or whatever is contained within my variable called "id".

Comment: If the variable `id` contains either the number `0` or the string `"0"`, it will work and return the object `{ "id": "00088" }`

Comment: Oh, you are Bergi - I didn't look, sorry. You are right, what you suggest works without having to use eval at all. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, [it works without `eval`](http://jsfiddle.net/HfgCC/1/) :-) Show us more of your code then, maybe the markup of those `.listitem`s