# Passing a variable into a function in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just curious why this doesn't work. If I pass the name 'book1' directly it works, but if I pass it through the function's parameter it doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
var add_to_page = function(item) {
    $('#item .name').text(item.name)
    //$('#book1 .name').text(book1.name) //<--- this works!!

};

add_to_page('book1');
```

Comment: `add_to_page(book1);` to pass the object or `$('#item .name').text(item)` if you pass a name

Comment: Duplicate of many. One of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084858/javascript-use-variable-as-object-name

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `book1` is an object, your mistake is that you are passing a string to `add_to_page()`. Try replacing

```
add_to_page('book1');
```

with

```
add_to_page(book1);
```

**EDIT**

The selector is wrong too. It should be obvious that `$("#item .name")` is not the same as `$("#book .name")`. What you seem to be trying to achieve cannot be accomplished, because you are trying to use one single argument (`item`) as a string in one place and as an object in another one.

Comment: @mplungjan Didn't realize, seems that you commented while I was posting the answer. However, why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Because it is not worth saving this question.

Comment: @mplungjan The question will not disappear, however, by not answering it. If you think it's duplicate or should be closed, then you should better flag it.

Comment: I did flag it and it is too simple to find a good duplicate. I cannot flag it twice

Comment: Yes book1 is an object. I tried that as well and still doesn't work.

Comment: @fokusfocus does it also have a `name` key?