# Want to create a dynamic array from javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

Am trying to develop stepwise like below:

1. Ask user to enter a array name using `prompt()`
2. Prompt user to enter total size of array.
3. Prompt user to enter each values...till it satisfies total size in step 2.
4. Build array and display in page or console.-

Steps 2, 3 & 4 was done, and got end product.
But am not sure how to build step 1.

```
arrayName = prompt('');
arrayLength = prompt('');
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    arrayItems = prompt('');
    arrayName[i] = arrayItems;
}
console.log(arrayName);
}
```

How to make `arrayName` appear as an array? Currently its returning only variable from prompt. I need `arrayName` variable input to be an array.

eg. If user input for first prompt be `"xyz"`, then `arrayName` will be `xyz`.
So that I can call `xyz[i]`. Is it possible to do that way. If yes, how could be?

Comment: this might help: [javascript-use-variable-as-object-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084858/javascript-use-variable-as-object-name)

Comment: Is `obj[xyz][i]` good for you ?

Comment: Why do you want the user to be able to choose the name of the variable in which the values are stored?! What's the use case?

Comment: window[arrayName] = [ ];

Comment: Thanks Kevin and br3t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build an object and assign the values accordingly. That way you can simply use bracket notation to create the name

```js
function build() {
  this._arrayName = prompt("name");
  this[this._arrayName] = [];
  this.arrayLength = prompt("length");
  for (var i = 0; i < this.arrayLength; i++) {
    this[this._arrayName].push(prompt("item"));
  }
  return this[this._arrayName];
}

console.log(build());
```

Comment: exact answer...Thanks :)