# How can I pass object as a parameter using a string of its name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
bigRow = {size:'long', color:'pink'};
```

Let's say I have another object `table`, which has `row` property, e.g.

```
table = {
    row: 'bigRow',
    column: 'smallColumn'
};
```

Can I pass the object 'bigRow' as a parameter to a function using `table`'s property value as a reference?

Can I write something like

```
function ( table.row )
```

that would work like

```
function ( bigRow )
```

Even though both turn out to be `function( bigRow )`, the former comes out as a string without any connection to the object

Comment: Make `bigRow` a property of `someContainerObject` and you can say `functionCall(someContainerObject[table.row])`.

Comment: You usually can (because JavaScript is so flexible/unstructured) but it sounds like a really bad idea. Usually there's a better value to store in `table` (e.g. instead of a string you could store the object itself) or if you really need to look things up by name, you use an object like this: `rows = { bigRow: { ... } };` then you can do `func(rows[table.row])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible that way. However, you could put `bigRow` inside another object like so:

```
var rowTypes = {
    bigRow : {size:'long', color:'pink'},
    //other rows if necessary...
}
```

And then access that member of the `rowTypes` object using the string as an identifier:

```
function ( rowTypes[table.row] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can but you should set your object as property of current document using "this" keyword.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
 this.bigRow = {size:'long', color:'pink'};
 this.table = {
    row: 'bigRow',
    column: 'smallColumn'
 };

 function myFunction(myRow){
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myRow.size;
  console.log(myRow);
 }

 myFunction(this[table.row]);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0p5afpj9/

Answer (score 0):

I came across an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084858/javascript-use-variable-as-object-name). Apparently, this will work if both objects are global:

```
function ( this[ table.row ] )
```