# Use value of $scope variable to specify a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a $scope variable that stores a vegetable like so:

```
$scope.selectedVegetable = 'carrot';
```

And I also have an object that contains properties of vegetables like so:

```
$scope.vegetableProperties = {
    carrot: {
        color: 'orange',
        tastiness: 3
    },
    onion: {
        color: white,
        tastiness: 1
    }
};
```

And now let's say that I want to use the value of `$scope.selectedVegetable` to help me specify the object/property in `$scope.vegetableProperties` that I am looking for.

What I'd like to do is something like...

```
$scope.selectedColor = $scope.vegetableProperties.$scope.selectedVegetable.color;
```

...rather than explicitly specifying the vegetable, as in:

```
$scope.selectedColor = $scope.vegetableProperties.carrot.color;
```

and expect a value of `orange`, but this does not work.

Basically, is there a way to use the value of one $scope variable to specify an object property on another $scope variable?

Comment: Bracket notation: `$scope.vegetableProperties[$scope.selectedVegetable].color`. I suggest you go through some introductory lessons on JS before tackling AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not specific to AngularJS, but you should be able to access object properties by variable like so: `$scope.selectedColor = $scope.vegetableProperties[$scope.selectedVegetable].color;`

[Javascript use variable as object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084858/javascript-use-variable-as-object-name)

Comment: Perfect, thank you much!