# how to make a variable of a nested object key

Tags: javascript

If I have the following code written where i'm trying to interchange  between `failedIds` and `passedIds`:

```
hideShowTestResults: function(failOrPass){
    if(this.[failOrPass ? passedIds : failedIds ].length > 0){} 
}
```

Yet this syntax is not accepted in JS, how would I go about this?

Thanks,
Bud

Comment: The object accessor required a `string` value, and after that you probably should not access `failedIds` once again. ALSO you should avoid `.` (dot) between this and the bracket

Comment: sorry, let me amend the question, syntax.

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084875/11907346) in a similar question.

Comment: Unrelated, but when there's "multi-level" logic like this it's almost always better to pull it out into a temp var and make the code that much easier to reason about.

Comment: `failOrPass` is a boolean variable? You shouldn't call it that if it is.

Comment: What do you do with the function, by the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- bracketed property access looks like `obj[prop]`, not `obj.[prop]`
- the property name is an expression that produces a string

```
if (this[failOrPass ? 'passedIds' : 'failedIds'].length > 0) {
```

Or, because selecting a property name is kind of less readable than selecting an array:

```
if ((failOrPass ? this.passedIds : this.failedIds).length > 0) {
```

Comment: This seems like a weird function, though. It might be better as two or more functions.

Comment: Noting that it'd be more readable, and reduce cognitive overhead, to pull this out into two statements.

Comment: I just did now : `let result = failOrPass ? this.passedIds : this.failedIds;` and then: `if(result.length > 0){}` but you answer is well invested, so i'll vote it soon when it allows